# What would I have to do to this navigation bar code to get it to go in the middle of the page rather than on the left?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

What would I have to do to this code to get the navigation bar to show up in the top center of my website rather than the left?

```
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}
```

I've tried inserting various strings into ".topnav" like "vertical-align: middle;" and "text-align: center;" and ".topnav ul {display: inline-block; list-style-type: none;}" but to no avail, what am I missing?

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Depending on the structure and which tags you used, that changes what CSS you would use to center your nav.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.